# Configure custom hibernate id generator in spring context

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am using Spring and Hibernate and I recently created a custom Id generator. Right now, on my Java domain object I have:

```
@GenericGenerator(name="...", strategy="com.acme.MyIdGenerator", ...)
```

Can I create/configure a `com.acme.MyIdGenerator` in my spring context and somehow have Hibernate use it instead of having Hibernate instantiate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to isolate your generator from the consumer class (or classes), you can define the generator in a package-info.java class. See [this example in the test suite](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/annotations/id/package-info.java).

But if you really want to map it in the XML, then you'll have to map that specific entity as a hbm.xml ([as seen here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id)) and add it to your Hibernate configuration in the Spring context.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could annotate package-info.java. Cool (+1)

Comment: I don't currently have an hbm.xml, everything is annotation based. Are you saying I'd have to create an hbm.xml to do this, even when I don't use one now?

Comment: @codecraig As I said, you can use the annotations approach, or, if you really need to add it as an XML, you should create a hbm.xml file, as you can't really configure the mappings using Spring. You just configure Hibernate (not mappings, AFAIK).