# How do I make Spring to instantiate Custom ID generator instead of hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to use a custom ID generator in Spring-MVC boot application.
But instead of Spring creating an instance of ID generator, hibernate is creating it and hence I am getting `NullPointerException` when I access autowired dependencies of ID generator.

How can I tell hibernate not to create an instance of the Custom ID generator and allow Spring to do it?

I tried adding `@Component` to custom ID generator class but it seems hibernate is creating an instance anyway.
I also went through [Configure custom hibernate id generator in spring context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624943/configure-custom-hibernate-id-generator-in-spring-context) but couldn't understand how to solve this problem.

Code Snippets are as below:

**Entity Class**

Entity Class: This is model class where I have mentioned in a strategy custom ID generator i.e KE_IDGenerator to be used.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TAB_Error")
public class KnownErrorDto {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="seq_id", strategy="x.x.x.x.IdGenerator.KE_IDGenerator"
            )
    @GeneratedValue(generator="seq_id")
    @Column(name ="KEID")
    String KEID;
}
```

**Dao Class**
Dao: In this interface, I have mentioned a method with native query which is giving next sequence value.

```
public interface KnownErrorDaoInterface extends CrudRepository<KnownErrorDto,Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT TAB_Err_SEQ.nextval  FROM dual", nativeQuery = 
                true)
     int getNextSeqForKnownError();
    
}
```

**Custom ID Generator class**

Custom-ID Generator: This is the class which is taking sequence value from Dao and supposed to return custom ID

```
public class KE_IDGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
    
    @Autowired
    KnownErrorDaoInterface knownErrorDaoInterface;
    
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object)
                    throws HibernateException {
            
        String prefix = "KE";
               
        int id=knownErrorDaoInterface.getNextSeqForKnownError();
        String keId=null;
    
        keId=prefix + StringUtils.leftPad("" + id,9, '0');
                return keId;
    }
}
```

I am getting below Error:

```
2019-07-21 20:11:11.165 ERROR 1900 --- [nio-8083-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at 
x.x.x.x.IdGenerator.KE_IDGenerator.generate(KE_IDGenerator.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
```

I expect KE_IDGenerator to generate custom ID using the sequence value provided by `KnownErrorDaoInterface`. But I am getting `null` pointer when I try to access `KnownErrorDaoInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `session` parameter from the `generate` method in your custom generator to execute native statements.
Doing so requires you to write custom SQL statements and eliminates the comfortability of Spring and Hibernate taking care of it, but it will do the job.

```
public class FimIdGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {
    
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {

        // The object, that shall get a new ID is provided as `Object object`
        // So feel free to cast it to your own entity
        if(object instanceof FimEntity){
            FimEntity entity = (FimEntity) object;

            String createQuery = "CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS MY_CUSTOM_SEQENCE_NAME"
            session.createSQLQuery(createQuery).executeUpdate();

            String nextValQuery = "SELECT NEXTVAL('MY_CUSTOM_SEQENCE_NAME')";
            BigInteger newId = (BigInteger) session.createSQLQuery(nextValQuery).getSingleResult();

            return newId;
        }else{
            throw new HibernateException("Only entities of super type FimEntity are supported");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this example uses a fixed sequence name, which is not what we both need, we need dynamic names. So what I did was:

On class level

```
private final static String CREATE_TEMPLATE = "CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS SEQ_%03d_%s START WITH 1";

private final static String NEXTVAL_TEMPLATE = "SELECT NEXTVAL('SEQ_%03d_%s');";
```

On `generate` method level (The `fimId` object is party of my entity and I just `getFimId()` on the casted `object`)

```
String createQuery = String.format(CREATE_TEMPLATE, fimId.getAppiid(), fimId.getEntityType());
session.createSQLQuery(createQuery).executeUpdate();

String nextValQuery = String.format(NEXTVAL_TEMPLATE, fimId.getAppiid(), fimId.getEntityType());
BigInteger newId = (BigInteger) session.createSQLQuery(nextValQuery).getSingleResult();
```

Doing so will create new sequences during runtime, e.g. "SEQ_001_tag" or tenant 1 and entity type tag or "SEQ_016_document" for tenant 16 and entity type document.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom Id generator `KE_IDGenerator` is not a spring managed bean and it will be managed by spring, so you can not inject any dependency in it. `knownErrorDaoInterface` will always be null. If you want to use an existing sequence table for id generation you can use it like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TAB_Error")
public class KnownErrorDto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="seq_name")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq_name",sequenceName="seq_table",allocationSize=10)
    @Column(name ="KEID")
    String KEID;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Rahil Husain.  But I do not want to use only the sequence value as my primary key. Also, even If I marked KE_IDGenerator as Component, spring is not creating an instance of KE_IDGenerator

Comment: Spring Will never create its instance. If you want to use any dependecy use a static helper method to get the KnownErrorDaoInterface bean